# lftp: login, put file in remote dir and exit in a single command: proper quoting help

Tags: shell, lftp

I want to use `lftp -c` to do an entire session in one go (as I'll be launching this from a script later on) and I managed with `-e` but that ofc leaves me with the interactive session which I don't want.

Manual states

```
-c commands
          Execute the given commands and exit. Commands can be separated with a semicolon,  `&&'
          or  `||'.  Remember to quote the commands argument properly in the shell.  This option
          must be used alone without other arguments.
```

But I don't understand how I should quote and string my commands/interactions together correctly.

`lftp -e "put -O remote/dir/ /local/file.txt" -u user,pass ftpsite.com` 
works excellent. But I want to exit after executing the command;

`lftp -c "open -u user,pass ftpsite.com" || put -O "remote/dir/ /local/file.txt"` 
just shouts at me, or in fact any combination of quotes I tried (`||` or `&&` regardless)

Comment: just add ;quit or ;bye :)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
$ lftp -c "open -u user,pass ftpsite.com; put -O remote/dir/ /local/file.txt"
```

should do it.

If this doesn't work try adding to your `/etc/lftp.conf` the following lines:

```
set ftp:ssl-protect-data true
set ftp:ssl-force true
set ftp:ssl-auth TLS
set ssl:verify-certificate no
```

Comment: is there anyway of making this work if the password has characters in it like `' " : ;`

Comment: I got tripped up, because I had a space after that first comma, once I figured that out it worked great

Answer (score 21):

`lftp -e "put -O remote/dir/ /local/file.txt; bye" -u user,pass ftpsite.com`

Comment: 'bye' is the key.

Answer (score 1):

`lftp -e "put -O remote/dir/ /local/file.txt; bye" ftp.yourhost.com`

and put your credentials under ~/.netrc like

`machine ftp.yourhost.com login your_username password your_password`

Putting passwords in the cli is absolutely no-go since those are even readable when using ps -aux during the upload.. beside the bash history also.