# lftp user credentials do not work with -e or -c

Tags: lftp

I would like to use `lftp` to put a file in a remote directory and exit in one command. Following the top answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93587/lftp-login-put-file-in-remote-dir-and-exit-in-a-single-command-proper-quoting) about this very task, I tried the following:

```
lftp -c "open -u user,pass ftpsite.com; put -O remote/dir/ /local/file.txt"
```

I received the following error:

> put: Login failed: 530 Box: Invalid user credentials.

I tried the second answer

```
lftp -e "put -O remote/dir/ /local/file.txt; bye" -u user,pass ftpsite.com
```

and received the same error.

Doing everything step-by-step worked perfectly, i.e.,

```
lftp ftpsite.com -u user,pass
put -O remote/dir/ /local/file.txt
bye
```

but I have to do this for many files. I would like to be able to do this in one command to run it as part of a script. Any tips on how to fix this error, or where to look/start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use `lftp` in most of my scripts to automate uploads/downloads and using HEREDOC syntax has always worked:

```
 lftp -u user,pass ftpsite.com << EOF
 cd remote/dir/ 
 put /local/file.txt
 bye
 EOF
```

Make sure you protect your password between `'` as it may contain reserved characters which get interpreted by the shell (and then not correctly passed to `lftp`): `lftp -u user,'password'`.

Comment: The result was `Unknown command \`-u'.`

Comment: @duckmayr sorry, the `-c` wasn't meant to be there. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit; that fixed the `Unknown command` issue, but I still get the `Login failed error`. I suspect it has to do with some kind of system/`lftp` setting, but I don't know enough about `lftp` to know really where to look.

Comment: @duckmayr It _might_ be that your password has some reserved character(s) which get interpreted by bash, for example `#` or `'` or `"` ? If thats the case, try enclosing password between `'`.

Comment: Thanks! I had the `lftp ftpsite.com -u user,pass` in my history with the password between `'`, but didn't make sure the password was between `'` when trying out the command version. Upvoted, will accept if you edit to include the bit about passwords and reserved characters (since that's technically what resolved the problem). Thanks again!